# Unexpected behavior of symfony2 in prod and dev mode for (The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!)

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.3

Please help!

Everything works fine in development mode, But in production i get the following error in log file

**i checked my log file by "tail -f app/logs/prod.log"**

> [2013-11-18 16:42:07] request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception BadMethodCallException: "Undefined method 'getHitCount'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy!" at /var/www/myproject/mis/trunk/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php line 196 {"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException: Undefined method 'getHitCount'. The method name must start with either findBy or findOneBy! at /var/www/myproject/mis/trunk/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityRepository.php:196)"} []

I tried lot and searched over internet also, but i think my problem seems different because symfony2 showing ambiguous role in  mode.

**FYI:**

1. I have `Created` repository class
2. This class has `getHitCount` function
3. I added `repositoryClass` key in `form.orm.yml` file.

Comment: Error seems like your "custom" repository is not configured right, maybe some missing namespace ? maybe the bundle is not listed in app kernel ? or is it listed inside the app kernel but mentioned inside the if environment is `dev` section ?

Comment: Hi nixoschu, Bundle is there and it is not in if condition of dev envioronment, As if i configured repository wrong than it should not work in dev mode as well, Thanks for your comment

Comment: tried to clear the cache ? :P

Comment: Yes I tried to clear cache before.
php app/console cache:clear --no-debug,
This also php app/console cache:clear,
rm -rf app/cache/prod
but in all cases fail
Always get that error in log file

Comment: I restarted apache2 server also after clearing cache, and gave write permission also on cache n logs

Comment: Hi nixoschu,Sorry and Thank you for your comment, As my i came to know, there is memcached configured in my project by other developer and i was unaware, It is working now by clearing memcached by 

telnet localhost portNumber

Comment: if its solved now, it was a pleasure for me :D